# What .NET Framework version and profile will come with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview, .net-framework

Is it already defined?
Will it be .NET Framework 4 or 4.5?
Will it be Client Profile or Full?
Will Extended and Multi-Targeting packs also be included?

Comment: I'm not asking for which versions will it support, but what comes already installed.

Comment: @Vam'çá - .NET 4.5 because that is the only version that Metro supports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [MS TechNet article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825211104/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/) says:

> Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 include .Net 4.5, which supports building and running the next generation of applications and web services, including Metro-style apps. .Net 4.5 supports applications written for 4.0, so there is no need to install .Net 4.0 on Windows 8.

The above article doesn't mention Client Profile and appears to apply to the desktop version of Windows 8, not the tablet version of Windows 8.

This article, [.NET in Windows 8](https://web.archive.org/web/20201029001939/http://geekswithblogs.net/simonc/archive/2012/03/28/.net-vs-windows-8.aspx), describes a stripped-down .NET in the tablet version of Windows 8.

Comment: The article describes the WinRT .NET Profile, which is similar to the Client Profile, but is required to be sold on the Windows Store.

Comment: Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available. Optimizations provided by the .NET Framework 4.5, such as smaller download size and faster deployment, have eliminated the need for a separate deployment package. The single redistributable streamlines the installation process and simplifies your app's deployment options.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this googled article:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **The .NET Framework 4.5 RC is included with Windows 8 Release Preview and installed on your computer with the operating system.** However,
>   the .NET Framework 3.5 is not automatically installed with Windows 8
>   Release Preview. To run applications that require the .NET Framework
>   3.5 on Windows 8 Release Preview, you must enable version 3.5 on your computer. There are two ways you can do this: by installing or running
>   an application that requires the .NET Framework 3.5 (that is, by
>   installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on demand), or by enabling the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 in Control Panel. Both options require an Internet
>   connection.

Additionally, according to another [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been
>   discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available.**
>   Optimizations provided by the .NET Framework 4.5, such as smaller
>   download size and faster deployment, have eliminated the need for a
>   separate deployment package. The single redistributable streamlines
>   the installation process and simplifies your app's deployment options.
>
> When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 RC, the .NET Framework 4
>   Client Profile is updated to the full version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: You don't have to install the .NET Framework 3.5 and/or 4.0 by itself, 4.5 has backward support, although most applications check specifically for 3.5 SP1 and 4.0

Comment: @Ramhound no, it is not true, I already tried to install some Win 7 apps based on .Net 3.5 and I was warned to install .net 3.5, some apps only works under 3.5 framework, 4.0 and 4.5 does not provide entire backward support.

Comment: @Diogo but you can still add a configuration file that tells the executable to use a newer version .NET Framework and run it without recompiling. Doing that the application can run into a series of compatibility issues though

Comment: @Vam'çá You mean a .config on exe folder?

Comment: @Diogo exactly!